# Internal JFrame Properties

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jinternalframe

I have a `JInternalFrame` as shown below.

[image]

Are there properties that allow for?

- coloring
- hiding the title bar
- adding text
- Further Customization*

to the top bar?

The only thing I have been able to find is:

```
jInternalFrame1.setTitle("Hello");
```

But I am more after a way to hide it etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set through it's constructor like button maximize, minimize, resize, icon etc

and http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Java-Beginners/1923-Hide/remove-titlebar-of-JInternalframe.html

[another example with multiple JInternalFrame](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/InterestingthingsusingJInternalFramesJDesktopPaneandDesktopManager2.htm)

Answer (score 1):

To remove all the decorations from the title bar you can create a smaller bar (in height) that will only allow the user to drag the internal frame:

```
frame.putClientProperty("JInternalFrame.isPalette", Boolean.TRUE);
```

To remove the title bar when using the Metal LAF you can use something like:

```
BasicInternalFrameUI ui = (BasicInternalFrameUI)frame.getUI();
Component north = ui.getNorthPane();
north.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(0, 0) );
north.validate();
```